# Subscription with credit/debit card with Paypal Developer API Standard

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm creating a website for a customer, he has a service that will be billed monthly (same price). The user should be able to pay with a PayPal account or with his debit/credit card.

I read the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/) according to my understanding the PayPal standard (the account that my customer has) just give the option of paying with a button and the user should use the PayPal account.

I want to know if this is possible because I didn't see any reference to it in the documentation or if it depends on the country of my customer (some answers say so) how I know in what countries is available (he is from Spain, but I'm from the Dominican Republic so maybe I wouldn't be able to test this feature).

Comment: better to ask paypal

Comment: Already done but no response yet so StackOverflow is listed in the support

Answer (score 0):

PayPal country availability is subject to change.

Please see this link: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/country-doesnt-work-paypal-66099.html

> ### What Country Doesn't Work With PayPal?
>
> <sup>by John Lister</sup>
>
> PayPal is available in some form in 191 countries as of May 2013. PayPal only offers limited service in some countries. It has no dealings whatsoever in some other countries, many of which are in the Middle East or Africa.
>
> #### Availability
>
> As of April 2013, PayPal offered full locally-based services in 26 countries. In another 18 countries you can have a PayPal account and transfer money to a local or US bank account. In India and Vietnam you can only transfer money to a local bank account. In a further 64 countries you can only withdraw money to a US bank account. In 83 other countries you can have a PayPal account but cannot withdraw money to a bank account.
>
> #### No Availability
>
> PayPal does not maintain a list of countries where it does not provide any service. However, a comparison of the United Nations' list of member states and the PayPal list of countries with some service shows 28 countries without service as of May 2013. These are: Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Cameroon, Central African Republic, Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast), Democratic People's Republic of Korea (North Korea), Equatorial Guinea, Gabon, Ghana, Haiti, Iran, Iraq, Lebanon, Liberia, Libya, Monaco, Moldova, Montenegro, Myanmar, Pakistan, Paraguay, Saint Lucia, South Sudan, Sudan, Syria, Timor-Leste, Uzbekistan and Zimbabwe.
>
> #### Rationale
>
> PayPal does not publicly detail why it does not service particular countries. Media speculation suggests common reasons could include insufficient regulation and security in a country's banking system, failure of a country to comply with U.S. tax law, or a U.S. trade ban affecting a country. The availability of PayPal in countries can and does change. For example, in April 2013 PayPal became available in Egypt for the first time.
>
> #### Restriction
>
> Although PayPal lets you change your address when you move, you cannot change your address to one in another country, even if PayPal operates in that country. If you move abroad, you have two options. You can close your account and open a new one, or you can have two accounts -- one account in your old country and one in the new one. However, the two accounts must be of different types (premier, personal or business) and must each be linked to a different e-mail address and bank account.

Comment: I don't know how this contributes to the answer, I'm not asking about the country availability of the PayPal service per se, just the PayPal developer API to pay with credit/debit/PayPal account and if is a feature that really has the standard PayPal payment.

Comment: Based on what I am understand, if the PayPal support in that country, they will support there credit/debit card, and credit card company will do the currency transfer or the bank will to the currency transfer for debit.

Comment: In other questions, the answers said that there is not always the pay with credit /debit card option is available and it sometimes depends on the country.